# Any tips on creating a Pygame Developer Console?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, console-application

I've been getting my feet wet with Python and Pygame, and after a few bugs in a very basic game that I have been making, I've thought to myself that having some sort of console that can deal with string input (from a developer) would be very handy.

Here's an example:

I notice the player disappears after double jumping. So, in the console that I will hopefully create, I would type in:

```
>> report_bug("Player disappears after double jumping")
```

Where `report_bug(string)` is a user-defined function that will do the following things:

```
report_bug(string):
    # Check if debug file already exists; create new file if none exists
    # Append string to file, along with other extra info
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Will I have to create something from scratch, and if so, how would I go about doing that? I've attempted to modify the source code from: http://www.pygame.org/project-pygame-console-287-.html, however it is 9 years-old and made for Python 2.x, when I'm using Python 3.4.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the 2.X PygameConsole version 0.7 working, so I will stick with that!

**Edit:** I will attempt to port PyConsole to Python 3.X and hopefully add some more features so newcomers can easily understand what is going on.